# intersection set between $z=2xy$(saddle) and $X-Z $ plane

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

[image][image]

how to find out a intersection set between $ z=2xy $ and $X-Z$ plane.

I already tried using $X-Z$ plane as $ y=0 $.
However, what I can get is just points on X-axis,

Intuitively, the intersection set should be a set of points shape like curve.
What's the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wrote 
$$
z = 2xy
$$ and 
$$
y = 0
$$
so 
$$
z = 2x \cdot 0
$$
so $z = x = 0$ and that's  my single point.

But that last equation has MANY solutions, namely, any triple of the form
$$
(x, 0, 0)
$$
where $x$ is any real number. In other words, you get the whole $x$ axis, which is a line.

Here's Matlab's picture of the situation:

[image]

created with this not-very-pretty code:

```
function mse
clf;
t = linspace(-1, 1, 10);
[x, y] = meshgrid(t, t);
z = 2 * x .* y; 
surf(x, y, z);
hold on; 

zz = y; 
yy = 0 * y; 
surf(x, yy, zz, yy);


plot3(t, 0*t, 0*t, 'r', 'LineWidth', 4);
figure(gcf)
hold off;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not match the picture right?

Comment: If you're asking whether algebra or software is correct, I'm betting on algebra every time (and I say that after a lifetime of writing software of one sort and another). I can't make sense of your figure, but the red line in the matlab figure that I've now included shows that at least ONE software package agrees with me.

Answer (score 0):

When $y=0$ for XZ plane,the product $ x \cdot y = 0 $ automatically from given saddle equation..we have $ z=0$.

And when $ y =0,z=0 $ are *combined*, these *two* equations represent the x-axis which is what you are seeking.

In this special case you will not get a curve as the cut line is the central asymptote to the entire set.But curves of intersection are obtained either if $y$ or if $z$ is non-zero.